# What's the result of assign a short to a unsigned char in an array?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, char, short

I got a short value(which can just be limited to a `UINT8`) and want to assign it to a `UINT8`(/`unsigned char`).
But I thought of no better choices, but to do this:

```
unlatch.FaultBits.Value[0] = ui->lineEditFaultBits->text().toShort();
```

But can this achieves what I want when I use `unlatch.FaultBits.Value[0]`?
(Vaule[] is an array in a struct: `UINT8    Value[64];`)

Comment: The result is that you assign the low-order 8 bits of the integer to the character.

Comment: Not sure what you're worried about, but I can confirm that this won't clobber memory (won't change Value[1]). It will simply shorten the value (taking the lowest-order byte) before assigning.

Comment: It does not "take the lowest-order byte". It reduces the value modulo 256 into the range [0,255]. These two operations are only the same if the original (signed) value is represented in twos complement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can this achieve what you want? Well, I can assume one of four avenues, because you haven't told us exactly what you want (grumble).

1. You want to assign the `short` value to a `uint8_t`, without signed-to-unsigned conversion. In this case, you must be sure that the old value is within the range of a `uint8_t`: `assert(old_value >= 0 && old_value <= 255);`. If this point describes the behaviour you desire and that assertion fails, then no, your code doesn't do what you want.
2. You want to assign a possibly negative or out-of-range `short` value to a `uint8_t` and you don't see a problem with the reduction process R described in his comment. If this point describes the behaviour you desire, then yes, your code does what you want.
3. You want to assign a possibly negative or out-of-range `short` value to a `uint8_t` and the reduction process R described in his comment doesn't work for you, but you are prepared to express your own reduction algorithm in your code. If this point describes the behaviour you desire, then no, you haven't expressed your custom reduction algorithm.
4. You want to assign a possibly negative or out-of-range `short` value to a `uint8_t` and you don't want want the value to be reduced. In this case, `uint8_t` is unsuitable. Select a different type.